# Pass a ComboBox as an argument in a Sub or Function

Tags: excel, vba, function, combobox

I have problems passing a ComboBox as an argument in a Subprocess. Before I used a subprocess to order the content of each ComboBox and what I try now is to reduce code.

I explain:
The form contains N ComboBox (1, 2, ... N) that is filled with the contents of a table column each. For example:

```
Set NColumn = TStaff.ListColumns("NameStaff").DataBodyRange
Me.ComboBox1.List = NColumn.value
SortComboBox1

Set IDColumn = TStaff.ListColumns("IDStaff").DataBodyRange
Me.ComboBox2.List = IDColumn.value
SortComboBox2

...

SortComboBoxN
```

The code used to order the content of each ComboBox is the following:

```
Private Sub SortComboBox1()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim sTemp As String
Dim LbList As Variant

LbList = Me.ComboBox1.List

For i = LBound(LbList, 1) To UBound(LbList, 1) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(LbList, 1)
        If LbList(i, 0) > LbList(j, 0) Then

            sTemp = LbList(i, 0)
            LbList(i, 0) = LbList(j, 0)
            LbList(j, 0) = sTemp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Me.ComboBox1.Clear

Me.ComboBox1.List = LbList
End Sub

Private Sub SortComboBox2()
...
End sub

...

Private Sub SortComboBoxN()
...
End sub
```

What I'm looking for is a subprocess that receives as an argument any ComboBox (or its content) and avoid repeating the same code to order each ComboBox.

My first approach was this but the "error 424" occurs (an object is required):

Modulo1:

```
Public CBox As ComboBox
```

UserForm(Code)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
...
Me.ComboBox1.List = NColumn.value
SortCBox (Me.ComboBox1)
Me.ComboBox2.List = IDColumn.value
SortCBox (Me.ComboBox2)
End Sub

Private Sub SortCBox(ByRef CBox As MSForms.ComboBox)
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim sTemp As String
Dim LbList As Variant

LbList = CBox.List 

For i = LBound(LbList, 1) To UBound(LbList, 1) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(LbList, 1)
        If LbList(i, 0) > LbList(j, 0) Then
            sTemp = LbList(i, 0)
            LbList(i, 0) = LbList(j, 0)
            LbList(j, 0) = sTemp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

CBox.Clear

CBox.List = LbList
End Sub
```

Where is the problem??
* If someone has another approach, thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in how you call the subroutine

```
SortCBox (Me.ComboBox1) ' <-- Wrong!
```

which will evaluate `Me.ComboBox1` depending on the default value, so most likely will call `SortCBox` with a string parameter - which is not what you want.

You should call the subroutine through

```
SortCBox Me.ComboBox1 ' <-- Right!
```

which will pass it through as intended.

The simple explanation is provided by Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-parentheses-in-code).

Comment: @Messi2019: The easy Stack Overflow way to thank someone is to accept their answer (the tick on the left hand side of the answer). Actually, this works across the full range of Stack Exchange.